# Shielding CPU from scheduler - How to move bound kernel threads from cores?

Tags: centos, cpu, scheduling, interrupt, multithreading

Suppose I have 4 physical cores (indexed 0-3) and I'm dedicating cores 1-3 to a shield for user applications and trying to steer all system threads onto core 0. I'm following the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11111852/how-to-shield-a-cpu-from-the-linux-scheduler-prevent-it-scheduling-threads-onto) and using `cset`:

```
# /usr/local/bin/cset shield --cpu 1-3  
cset: --> activating shielding:
cset: moving 145 tasks from root into system cpuset...
[==================================================]%
cset: "system" cpuset of CPUSPEC(0) with 145 tasks running
cset: "user" cpuset of CPUSPEC(1-3) with 0 tasks running
```

However, I don't seem to be able to move all my kernel threads onto core 0:

```
# cset shield --kthread on
cset shield --kthread on
cset: --> activating kthread shielding
cset: kthread shield activated, moving 175 tasks into system cpuset...
[==================================================]%
cset: **> 30 tasks are not movable, impossible to move
cset: done
```

The [Ubuntu man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/cset-shield.1.html) says that the `--kthread` flag only applies to **unbound** kernel threads:

```
   -k on|off, --kthread=on|off
       shield from unbound interrupt threads as well
```

so I presume I need to move the **bound** kernel threads away from cores 1-3 as well. How do I do that? (Preferably on CentOS.)

Comment: AFAIK, Except patching the Linux kernel threre is no way.